# how to decode json in qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5, qtcore

i want to decode following json with qt:

```
{
 "user": {
  "name": "string"
 }
}
```

i'm tried to do it with this code, but does not work:

```
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(result.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();
QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["user"].toArray();
foreach (const QJsonValue & value, jsonArray)
        {
            QJsonObject obj     = value.toObject();
            url          = obj["name"].toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
QJsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["user"].toArray();
```

You are trying to convert the object to an array without any  `isArray()` check. That is, your json does not contain an array therein. Array means `[...]` in the json world.

You ought to either use `toObject()` or change your input json.

Without json file change, you would write this:

```
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(result.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();
QJsonObject userJsonObject = jsonObject.value("user").toObject();
qDebug() << userJsonObject.value("name").toString();
```